# VBA Dynamic Range VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and need get some help with a VLOOKUP?

I keep getting Compile error for Expected: end of statement

This is the line that is giving me problems.

I added the & sign after (row_number) and am now getting a run-time error '9':  Subscript out of range error.

```
Sheets("WIP Count").Range("G" & (row_number)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & (row_number) & ",PRISM!L:T,8,FALSE)"
```

Here is the rest of the code.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
q1_answer = Sheets("Tracker").Range("F8")
q2_answer = Sheets("Tracker").Range("F9")
q3_answer = Sheets("Tracker").Range("F10")
q4_answer = Sheets("Tracker").Range("F11")

    If q1_answer = "" Then
        MsgBox "Fill in Name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

     If q2_answer = "" Then
        MsgBox "Fill in Serial Number"
        Exit Sub
    End If

     If q3_answer = "" Then
        MsgBox "Fill in Part Number"
        Exit Sub
    End If

     If q4_answer = "" Then
        MsgBox "Fill in Quantity"
        Exit Sub
    End If


row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
    item_in_review = Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("A" & row_number)

Loop Until item_in_review = ""

last_transaction_id = Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("A" & (row_number - 1))

Dim next_transaction_id As Integer
next_transaction_id = last_transaction_id + 1

Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("A" & (row_number)) = next_transaction_id
Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("B" & (row_number)) = q1_answer
Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("C" & (row_number)) = q2_answer
Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("D" & (row_number)) = q3_answer
Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("E" & (row_number)) = q4_answer
Sheets("WIP_Count").Range("F" & (row_number)).Value = Date
Sheets("WIP Count").Range("G" & (row_number)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & (row_number) & ",PRISM!L:T,8,FALSE)"

Sheets("Tracker").Range("F8") = ""
Sheets("Tracker").Range("F9") = ""
Sheets("Tracker").Range("F10") = ""
Sheets("Tracker").Range("F11") = ""

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need another `&` after `(row_number)`

Comment: I'm now getting a subscript out of range after I added the &

Comment: Using [edit], please update the original post with the corrected code line, so we can see exactly what you did.

Comment: If you are getting that on this line then there is a spelling error on the worksheet name.  Double check that there is not a space where there should not.  For example: all your other references has `_` instead of a space between the words.

Comment: Works now!  Thank you. Yes I misspelled my sheet name.  Thank you for the quick responses.